# Batch file error: "cant be processed syntactically at this point"

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, crash-reports

My batch-file program always crashes at the same point. What always happens before it crashes is this:

```
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 1>nul: 2>nul:

-n cant be processed syntactically at this point.

if ping -n 1 127.0.0.1|find "(0" >nul && goto Loop
```

And then the window closes.

Could maybe someone help me fix the problem?
This is the whole script:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:Loop

set ipaddr=127.0.0.1

ping -n 6 %ipaddr% >nul: 2>nul:

if ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(0%" >nul && goto Loop

echo Connection lost

start "" http://www.google.com


else if ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(100%" >nul && goto Loop

echo Connection OK

taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq google*" goto Loop

endlocal
```

Comment: remove the `if`. `&&` is doing that for you. It works as "if previous command (`find`) was successful, then"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an advanced Version with two blocks of code that are executed dependent of whether Connection is ok or lost.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set ipaddr=127.0.0.1
:Loop
ping -n 6 %ipaddr% >nul: 2>nul:
ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(0%" >nul && (
  echo Connection OK
  taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq google*" 
) || (
  echo Connection lost
  tasklist /v /fi "Windowtitle eq google*" || start "" http://www.google.com
)
goto :Loop
```

This is the "conventional way" with %errorlevel% and `if`- `else` (same logic, the above is just a shorter way of doing it):

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set ipaddr=127.0.0.1
:Loop
ping -n 6 %ipaddr% >nul: 2>nul:
ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(0%" >nul 
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Connection OK
  taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq google*" 
) else (
  echo Connection lost
  tasklist /v /fi "Windowtitle eq google*" || start "" http://www.google.com
)
goto :Loop
```

I took `set ipaddr...` out of the Loop. No Need to do it again and again.

(just wondering, if Google would be reachable, if the Connection got lost...)

*EDIT* to reflect the [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657786/batch-file-error-cant-be-processed-syntactically-at-this-point/34658101?noredirect=1#comment57087964_34658101). A bit enhanced, so any action only happens, if the connection status changes. Delete the "log" function if you don't need it, or redirect them to a file, if you like.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ipaddr=127.0.0.1
set "status=undefined"

:Loop
ping -n 2 %ipaddr% >nul: 2>nul:
ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(0%" >nul && (

  set oldstatus=!status!
  set status=online
  if !status! neq !oldstatus! (
    echo %date% %time% Connection switched from !oldstatus! to !status!
    taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq google*" >nul 2>&1
  )

) || (

  set oldstatus=!status!
  set status=offline
  if !status! neq !oldstatus! (
    echo %date% %time% Connection switched from !oldstatus! to !status!
    start "" http://www.google.com
  )

)
goto :Loop
```

Comment: I now just noticed that it opens the browser every time when it goes threw the "else". My goal would be, that it opens the browser just once, when it loses the connection, and then just keeps checking it. In case that it reconnects, it closes the browser again and everything starts from the beginning. Do you have an idea how I could realize this? (Ps: I know ^^ google was just an example, the site which is meant to be opened in the final version does not require am internet connection)

Comment: See my edit. It opens the site, if Connection gets lost and again if user closed it and the Connection is still down.

Comment: I see. So if you try the program using an IP which isnt reachable, then it opens the browser as it should. But then it goes back to the beginning of the script and the effect of that is, that the script then opens the google tab all the time, because it goes threw the "else" every time. My idea is, that it opens the browser just once, and not numerous times, and then keeps checking the connection and closes the browser if the IP is reachable again.